# how to show the current year month and previous year month together

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
IF V_MONTH='ALL' THEN
  V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM := (SUBSTR(V_YEAR, 1, 4) - 1 || '04')::NUMERIC;
  V_YEAR_MONTH_TO := (SUBSTR(V_YEAR, 6, 4) - 1 || '03')::NUMERIC;
ELSE
  IF V_MONTH IN ('01', '02', '03') THEN
    V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM := (SUBSTR(V_YEAR, 6, 4) || V_MONTH)::NUMERIC;
    V_YEAR_MONTH_TO := (SUBSTR(V_YEAR, 6, 4) || V_MONTH)::NUMERIC;
  ELSE
    V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM := (SUBSTR(V_YEAR, 1, 4) || V_MONTH)::NUMERIC;
    V_YEAR_MONTH_TO := (SUBSTR(V_YEAR, 1, 4) || V_MONTH)::NUMERIC;
  END IF;
END IF;
```

In the above query is working fine for getting details of current financial year 2023- 2024, when passing the value in input.
But now I have to given input 2023-2024
I want to show the data of current financial year and -1 financial year also simultaneously.
In this case, I want to show the data of 2023-2024 and 2022-2023.

Comment: Postgre Sql I am using for this code.above code is working fine for the current financial year.now from the above query what modification I want to do so that I can get current and previous financial year details

Comment: This appears to be a fragment from a PL/pgSQL procedure. Please provide additional context to clarify how the values are used. Why are you manipulating strings to process dates? A better approach might be to use a native `DATE` type to perform the adjustments and then format the results to achieve the desired text representations. The resulting code should then be simpler and more clearly express the intended operations.

Comment: I am trying to generate a certain report, where in the input we are getting year value as 2023-2024. So from the above code on the basis of month and year I am generating a report. Now the requirement is from the year 2023-2024 , with that year I have to show the -1 previous year report in the same way .so what modification need to add in the code so I get the report of both current and -1 year data in report.

Comment: Don't add unnecessary tags to your question. If you aren't using Oracle then don't tag it.

Comment: There is insufficient detail provided. None of the code in the question creates a report: it only shows manipulation of variables. How are these variables used to generate a report? The code you've provided is not a query, but is instead a block of procedural code.

Comment: This block is determining values for `V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM` and `V_YEAR_MONTH_TO` based on the conditions specified for the variable `V_MONTH`. If `V_MONTH` is 'ALL', it calculates a range for the entire year. If a specific month is provided, it calculates a range for that month within the given year.

Comment: IF V_MONTH = 'ALL' THEN
    V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM := (CAST(SUBSTRING(V_YEAR, 1, 4) AS INTEGER) - 1 || '04')::NUMERIC;
    V_YEAR_MONTH_TO := (CAST(SUBSTRING(V_YEAR, 1, 4) - 1 AS INTEGER) || '03')::NUMERIC;
ELSE
    IF V_MONTH IN ('01', '02', '03') THEN
        V_YEAR_MONTH_FROM := (CAST(SUBSTRING(V_YEAR, 6, 4) AS INTEGER) - 1 || V_MONTH)::NUMERIC;
        V_YEAR_MONTH_TO := (CAST(SUBSTRING(V_YEAR, 6, 4) AS INTEGER) - 1 || V_MONTH)::NUMERIC;

Comment: Repeating what is already in the post adds neither clarity nor context. You haven't described the allowed format or content of `V_MONTH` or `V_YEAR`. Don't use strings to manipulate or pass dates, use native `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` types. Don't use concatenated strings to represent ranges. Passing separate `from` and `to` arguments more clearly expresses the purpose of the values.The significance of `V_MONTH IN ('01', '02', '03')` is not at all clear.